# Ionic page does not cover the entire upper screen, leaving the date, time and antenna on the page

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing an application in Ionic 6, which I have not been able to make the page cover the entire upper screen, the date, time and antenna remain on the page.

I leave some images for more detail.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Status Bar` [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar) to hide the Status Bar.